# How to find server name while connecting to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

After I downloaded SQL Server Management Studio from here: [Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

I can't find server name while I try to connect to SQL Server.

I tried a lot of way like using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` and I use `devicename\MSSQLSERVER` and it doesn't help at all it shows me this message:

> Cannot connect to .\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

I saw a way to solve this, by opening SQL Server Configuration Manager, but this program is not installed with SQL Server Management Studio above . so how can i fix this ?

Comment: @marc_s your comment looks like the correct answer

Comment: @marc_s thanks a lot , This solve my problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed only the SQL Server Management Studio - you only have the GUI management tool - but **NOT** any actual database server.

You need to also download and install SQL Server itself - get the free Express edition from here: microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994

**Then** you can connect to a server using `.\SQLEXPRESS` (if you use all the defaults when installing)